# Avoiding overflow in computing the ratio of two large numbers

Tags: numerical-analysis

Is there a trick for computing the expression 
$x + (exp(x)-x)/(exp(2*x) + 1)$ while avoiding an overflow? 
Currently, computation seems to fail for any $x \geq 710$, presumably because computing $exp(2*x)$ leads to an overflow. The expression as such never produces particularly large numbers, but exponentiation seems to cause problems.

I'm working in R, but the same problem occurs in C++ as well.

If there is no trick for computing it, I'd be just as happy using another non-negative monotonic function which is nearly linear for $x > 10$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when $x\ge355$, computing $e^{2x}$ as [a double-precision float in IEEE 754-1985 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Double_precision), leads to an overflow.

$$x + \frac{e^x-x}{e^{2x} + 1}= x + e^{-x} - \frac{x+e^{-x}}{e^{2x} + 1}\approx x+ e^{-x}$$

The difference between the two sides of the approximate sign is smaller than the minimal positive number in IEEE 754-1985 standard, $2^{−1022} \approx 2.225×10^{−308}$, when $x>367.2$.

So, once $x>367.2$, you can just use $x+e^{-x}$ instead.